# Add new Language resource file for C# App

Tags: c#, .net

I have a multilingual C# WinForms Application which uses Resource Files for the multilang texts. Is there a possibility to add new Resource files containing other languages without recompiling the app.

Ultimately the goal is to give the customer the possibility to translate his app into various languages and deploy the new language / resource files without ever needing us to recompile the whole app.

Comment: you can recompile the code in local and override on production.

Comment: yes it is very possible but we have to see something did to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for "Satellite Assemblies". there is a very good explanation + tutorial on MSDN site: [Creating Satellite Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just create your resx file and compile it independently using resgen.

"The Resource File Generator (Resgen.exe) converts text (.txt or .restext) files and XML-based resource format (.resx) files to common language runtime binary (.resources) files that can be embedded in a runtime binary executable or satellite assembly. (See Creating Resource Files for Desktop Apps.)"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A Resource file is an embedded resource; thus it is not possible to add and use a new resource file without compiling. An option maybe employing satellite assemblies.

On the otherhand, you may just use xml files to store necessary data, then using a naming convention based on the culture, the application may read resources from the related xml file.

Answer (score 0):

for every  GUI component create an XML document
so if you fix the language your application will deserialize the xml documents and Fill the new value
i don't know something more easy